# What is the good way to provide an authentication in FASTAPI?

Tags: authentication, fastapi

what is the best way to provide an authentication for API. I read about authentication, Given an approach to write user: str = Depends(get_current_user) for each every function. I don't think so this is the good way to write an authentication. Can we erite a middleware for it, and add a userid to request object, so that we can take that in the API request processing. Could you any send me the middleware if some one already written.

Answer (score 8):

There is already good implementations in:

- [fastapi_contrib](https://github.com/identixone/fastapi_contrib)
- [fastapi-users](https://github.com/frankie567/fastapi-users)

Comment: Also [fastapi_login](https://github.com/MushroomMaula/fastapi_login)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I wanted to check Basic Authentication using middleware.

Here is a simple solution

```py
from fastapi import Request, FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
import base64

app = FastAPI()

def check_permission(method, api, auth):
    # The following paths are always allowed:
    if method == 'GET' and api[1:] in ['docs', 'openapi.json', 'favicon.ico']:
        return True
    # Parse auth header and check scheme, username and password
    scheme, data = (auth or ' ').split(' ', 1)
    if scheme != 'Basic': 
        return False
    username, password = base64.b64decode(data).decode().split(':', 1)
    if username=='john' and password=='test123':
        return True

@app.middleware("http")
async def check_authentication(request: Request, call_next):
    auth = request.headers.get('Authorization')        
    if not check_permission(request.method, request.url.path, auth):
        return JSONResponse(None, 401, {"WWW-Authenticate": "Basic"})
    return await call_next(request)


@app.get("/test")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

When the user tries to access `/test` it will fail with 401 unless the correct credentials are supplied.  This works ok in Swagger also. You don't get the padlock icon, but you do get the login pop-up (assuming Chrome is configured correctly).